# refactoring if else

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am refactoring a legacy code. There is a big if else statement. Is that  a pattern I can use. I have used a dictionary in the past for if-else but this has lot of (&&) so don't know how to refactor this.

for eg the code is

```
    public void ChangeControlVisibiltiy()
      {
        if (name != "I")
        {
           //Do something
        }



        if ((name != "A") && (name != "B") && (name != "C") && (name != "D") && (name != "F") && (name != "G") && (name != "H") && (name != "I") && (name != "J") && (name != "H") && (name != "I") && (name != "J"))
        {
           //Do something
        }

        if ((name != "A") && (name != "B") && (name != "D") && (name != "F") && (name != "G") && (name != "H") && (name != "I") && (name != "J") && (name != "H") && (name != "I") && (name != "J"))
        {
            //Do something

        }

        if ((name != "A"))
        {
            //Do something
        }


        if ((name != "A") && (name != "K") && (name != "L") )
        {

           //Do something
        }


        if ((name != "A") && (name != "K") && (name != "L") && (name != "B") && (name != "D") && (name != "F") && (name != "G") && (name != "H") && (name != "I") && (name != "J") && (name != "H") && (name != "I"))
        {
                //Do something
        }


        if ((name != "A") && (name != "L"))
        {

           //Do something
        }

        if (name == "M")
        {
           //Do something
        }

        else if (name == "C")
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else
        {
          //Do something
        }

        }
```

Comment: `if ((Name == "A") && (Name == "B")` is impossible to be true

Comment: Is this the real code? Because the middle two `if` statements are just redundant - a string can never equal both `"A"` and `"B"`.

Comment: How can a single string equal A,B and C at the same time?

Comment: appologies this is not real code.

Comment: Name can be either A, B or C...use switch case instead

Comment: Its impossible without a real example to provide an answer, please read [ask]

Comment: You may rename your variables and some values for the sake of confidential. However, can you double check if those conditions are indeed equivalent to what your actual code does?

Comment: Name is set from the query string . So it can have different values. This is just a small piece..but its a huge if else with more than 15 conditions. Is there a design pattern I can use?

Comment: let me edit it and post it ..sorry about this.

Comment: Your edit hasn't made it any easier since `// do something` could be anything, based on your initial edit, are you trying to show a `controlX` if name equals `X`?

Comment: @Sayse OP seems like they would be satisfied simply refactoring the conditions presented.

Comment: @KyleT - Being satisfied and being given a more correct scalable solution are two different things. Edit: Also op is this winforms/wpf/asp.net?

Comment: the code was badly writen. I found that I can have a single condition for a action . so the dictionary works.

Comment: @tester - The reason I was asking what you were using is you may be able to use [`FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) - i.e `FindControl("control" + Name").Visible = true` (missing error handling here). This would remove the entire if statement / and any dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this to multiple `switch` branches:

```
    public void ChangeControlVisibiltiy() {
        char c;
        if(name.Length == 1) {
            c = name[0];
        } else {
            c = '\0';
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'I':
                break;
            default:
                //1. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
            case 'D':
            case 'F':
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
            case 'J':
                break;
            default:
                //2. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'D':
            case 'F':
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
            case 'J':
                break;
            default:
                //3. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
                break;
            default:
                //4. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                break;
            default:
                //5. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'D':
            case 'F':
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                break;
            default:
                //6. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'A':
            case 'L':
                break;
            default:
                //7. Do something
                break;
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 'M':
                //8. Do something
                break;
            case 'C':
                //9. Do something
                break;
            default:
                //10. Do something
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be wise to add multiple cases running the same code as this will more closely match the requirement above

Comment: This code is evaluates equal to the code in the author's question

Comment: It is obvious that the code the op provided doesn't match their real code. Without a correct example, it isn't possible to say whether this is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, in your code you have *action per condition*. It may looks *shorter* if you have *condition per action* (but it's only syntax sugar and you can't utilize branching power to reduce number of actions itself):

```
controlA.Visibile = someConditionA ? true : false;
controlB.Visibile = someConditionB ? true : false;
controlC.Visibile = someConditionC ? true : false;
```

In given example `? true : false` part can be omitted, I provided it for clarity, showing you can set action parameter value this way.

You still have to use branching (`if`/`else`) to avoid some actions from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks a bit awkward but you could just remove the 2. and 3. if statement. If you have only a single parameter to check you can also use a switch statements.

Nevertheless you should use .equals() instead of == and please give us a real working code example. In general if you have the same code over and over again with a certain pattern just extract it into a new method e.g. if you have often smth like `Name.equals("A") || Name.equals("B")` just make a new method like `oredEquals(String name, String... matches)`.